# Controling privacy in Einstein Email Recommendations (Personalization Builder)

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations, data-protection-and-privacy

I'm trying to understand the mechanics of Email Recommendation, especially in terms of privacy.

I have a client keen to get it working, initially only **Content Catalogue**.

A former colleague left a document which I sent to the client and includes the scripts below (which can also be found in the implementation instructions).

**Step 1 - Collect Tracking Code Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//100000000.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
```

**Step 2 - Step 2 - Set Business Unit MID Script**

```
<scripttype="text/javascript">
_etmc.push(["setOrgId","100000000"]);
_etmc.push(["doNotTrack"]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
</script>
```

**Step 3 - Update Content Catalogue Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">_etmc.push(["updateItem",
_etmc.push(["setOrgId","100000000"]);  
{item_type:"content",
item:window.location.hostname.concat(window.location.pathname).replace("www.",""),
url:window.location.href,
available:"Y",
Name:document.title}])
</script>
```

The idea is to begin to build and update a content catalogue using the base URL as the unique identifier of the content. At a later stage, additional variables would be included.

Now the client is asking how to we control this from a GDPR perspective, allowing subscribers to opt out tracking. According to the documentation ([Manage Einstein Recommendations Customer Profile Data Privacy](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_delete_a_personalization_builder_customer_profile.htm&type=5)), it's possible to manually suppress or delete a subscriber from tracking, but is there a way of automating this?